# sql - select all rows that have all multiple same cols

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division, postgresql-11

I have a table with 4 columns.

- date
- store_id
- product_id
- label_id

and I need to find all store_ids that have all products_id with same label_id (for example 4)in one day.

for example:

```
store_id | label_id | product_id | data|
   4          4           5         9/2
   5          4           7         9/2
   4          3           12        9/2
   4          4           7         9/2
```

so it should return 4 because it's the only store that contains all possible products with label 4 at one day.

I have tried something like this:

```
(select store_id, date
from table
where label_id = 4
group by store_id, date
order by date)
```

I dont know how to write the outer query, I tried:

```
select * from table
where product_id = all(Inner query)
```

but it didnt work.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `where label_id = 4 and date = ... `?

Comment: Store 4 would also be shown for label 3, as for label 3 there was only one product sold on 9/2 and store 4 sold that product. Shall your query be looking at one particular label or all labels? Shall your query look for one particular day or all days? And can you please show the expected result? Do you just want to show store numbers? Or store and date? Or what else?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner my query should return all store_id's which contains all possible products for label_id =4 for day, the wanted output should be 4 because it's the only store that contains all the products for that day. in store 4 I have products id's - 5,7 and in store_id =5 I have only product_id = 7..

Comment: Okay, you want to show all stores that match this requirement, no matter on what day. A result may be 4 and you would know that store 4 sold all label 4 products on some day that were sold then, but you wouldn't know which day. What is your DBMS?

Comment: right.. postgres 11

Comment: Is product count is static?

Comment: `all products_id` How do you know **all** product_ids? Maybe there exists a product with id=13, which is not present in *this* table.

Comment: no, I meant all product_ids for given day, in the example I'm looking for a store that contains products 5 and 7..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear from your question whether the labels are specific to a given day or through the entire period.  But a variation of Tim's answer seems appropriate.  For *any* label:

```
SELECT t.date, t.label, t.store_id
FROM t
GROUP BY t.date, t.label, t.store_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.product_id) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2product_id)
                                       FROM t t2
                                       WHERE t2.label = t.label
                                      );
```

For a particular label:

```
SELECT t.date, t.store_id
FROM t
WHERE t.label = 4
GROUP BY t.date,t.store_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.product_id) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2product_id)
                                       FROM t t2
                                       WHERE t2.label = t.label
                                      );
```

If the labels are specific to the date, then you need that comparison in the outer queries as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT date, store_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY date, store_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_id)
                                     FROM yourTable t2
                                     WHERE t2.date = t1.date)
ORDER BY date, product_id;
```

This query reads in a pretty straightforward way, and it says to find every product, on some date, whose distinct product count is the same as the distinct product count on the same day, across all stores.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably aggregate to lists of products in a string or array:

```
with products_per_day_and_store as
(
  select
    store_id,
    date,
    string_agg(distinct product_id order by product_id) as products
  from mytable
  where label_id = 4
  group by store_id, date
)
, products_per_day
(
  select
    date,
    string_agg(distinct product_id order by product_id) as products
  from mytable
  where label_id = 4
  group by date
)
select distinct ppdas.store_id
from products_per_day_and_store ppdas
join products_per_day ppd using (date, products);
```